# Caret Binary Classification with RMSE

Tags: r, r-caret

Is there a way to get caret to use RMSE with a binary classification problem?

If you try to use `metric = "RMSE"` with a classification problem you will receive the message:

```
Error in train.default(x, y, weights = w, ...) :
    Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models
```

Which makes sense. But is there a way to define a custom metric? For example, if your outcome is `0` or `1`, you can define the error as `outcome - p` where `p` is the probability predicted by the model.

EDIT ====================

To give this some context and for some reasoning behind wanting to use this measure, see 2.7.1 in [An Experimental Analysis of Classifier Ensembles for Learning Drifting Concepts Over Time in Autonomous Outdoor Robot Navigation](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=BRcNAJotB4IC&pg=PA28&lpg=PA28&dq=rmse+for+binary+classifier&source=bl&ots=zrlPo2HNPm&sig=lTbHvVyOFHH6kvVBrUSU-kwAS4Q&hl=en&sa=X&ei=vX6gUozPIuqu7AbvvICoAg&ved=0CD8Q6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=rmse%20for%20binary%20classifier&f=false) by Michael J. Procopio, or the [paper on softclassval](http://softclassval.r-forge.r-project.org/2013/2013-01-03-ChemomIntellLabSystTheorypaper.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why you would want to do this but you can make your own summary function:

```
library(caret)

set.seed(1)
dat <- twoClassSim(100)

foo <- function(data, lev = NULL, model = NULL) {
  probs <- data[, lev[1]]
  c(rmse = RMSE(pred = probs,
                obs = ifelse(data$obs == lev[1], 1, 0)))
}

ctrl <- trainControl(classProbs = TRUE,
                     summaryFunction = foo)
set.seed(2)
mod <- train(Class ~ ., data = dat,
             method = "lda",
             metric = "rmse",
             minimize = TRUE,
             trControl = ctrl)
```

Max

Comment: sorry to come back to you on this. I can't work out from [these docs](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/training.html) how to make caret select the model with the minimal value. The example above selects the model with the largest RMSE (replace "lda" with "rf" to reproduce).

Comment: My edit above doesn't seem to have been accepted. To reproduce problem, run above code with `method = "rf"`. My proposed fix is to change `minimize = TRUE` to `maximize = FALSE`.

Answer (score 8):

Y should be a factor. Use as.factor() on it before training the model.

Comment: Thanks! This solved my "Metric RMSE not applicable for classification models" error doing binomial train() on y where y was a logical (boolean). Per your tip, I converted y from boolean to factor using as.factor() and problem was resolved. Talk about a cryptic error message!

Comment: In my case, Y is already a factor and I still got this error. So this may have solved a specific use case, but is not a generally acceptable solution, I think.